# How to output json file without carriage return in column name generating json with SQL Server Management Studio 12.7

Tags: json, sql-server, bcp

There is a problem in JSON file generated by bcp in a stored procedure.

Column names have a carriage return. So web server does not understand the JSON.

Like this:

**1.** `"leo_profit":-0.0748},{"ID":28977,"annual_profit":-0.84,"ttp":-455.8405,`

**2.**`"leo_profit":-0.0748},{"ID":28977,"annual_profit":-0.84,"ttp":-455.8405,`

The first one is generated by bcp in stored procedure of SQL Server 2017, as you see, there is a CR between column name "ann" and "ual_profit". `annual_profit` is column name.

Second one is JSON format that web server can understand.

How to make bcp in stored procedure generate without any CR between a column name?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @command    VARCHAR(1000)   
SET @command = 'BCP "EXEC mdrcoin.dbo.SP_Get_ANNUAL_PROFIT_FOR_JSON " queryout "D:\inetpub\json\SP_Get_ANNUAL_PROFIT.json" -c -T -t "|" '
EXEC xp_cmdshell @command
```

bcp is running in stored procedure shown above.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 7200 
        ID, 
        CAST(annual_profit AS DECIMAL(20,2)) AS annual_profit, 
        CAST(ttp AS DECIMAL(20,4)) AS ttp, 
        tr_year, 
        tr_month, 
        tr_day, 
        tr_hour, 
        tr_min, 
        CAST(btc AS DECIMAL(20,1)) AS btc, 
        CAST(cash_rate AS DECIMAL(20,4)) AS cash_rate, 
        CAST(leo_profit AS DECIMAL(20,4)) AS leo_profit
    FROM [dbo].[Q_annual_profit_flow] 
    ORDER BY tr_date DESC 
    FOR JSON path
```

this is another stored procedure named `SP_Get_ANNUAL_PROFIT_FOR_JSON`